# Android DropBox Sync API issues

Tags: android, dropbox-api

So I am trying to implement dropbox sync API into my application. I am following the code from the official dropbox tutorial which is:

```
static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;  // This value is up to you

public void onClickLinkToDropbox(View view) {
    mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // ... Start using Dropbox files.
        } else {
            // ... Link failed or was cancelled by the user.
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run my app and try to click the button to trigger it I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager.startLink(android.app.Activity, int)' on a null object reference
```

Any idea why (Activity)this is returning null or how I can reference the current context better?

Comment: It seems to me that this message probably indicates that `mDbxAcctMgr` is null. Where are you initializing it?

Comment: I'm initializing it like this: private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;

Comment: Well, that will cause you to have a null variable. Where do you actually assign it a value? E.g. from https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android you should have a line like `mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(...)`.